# No Python At ... problems with PATH of pip3

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd, path, pip

I think this problem splits to sub-problems starting with PATH.
I don't know why pip3 is calling a non-existent path that isn't 
written in the PATH variable. 
I've added a picture showing the problem more clearly.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6fKF.png]

Basically: I have no such path that pip3 claims to look at in PATH
so why does it look there? and more importantly how do I configure this?

Comment: "python3.7" and "python3" are from the app distribution of Python from the Microsoft Store. Your system appears to have a pip3.exe in `PATH` from the "Scripts" directory of a per-user python.org installation that's no longer installed. Run `where pip3.exe` to confirm this. If so, remove that directory from `PATH` in the system environment-variable editor. Also, if this old Python installation at "%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python37-32" really is no longer installed, you can delete the directory entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.
The problem was with a virtual environment that directed
the path for old removed path. I found it by using the `$ where pip`.

I have Removed the problematic virtual environment and
the python path in my PATH was not overwritten anymore.